# Firefox bug with regex positive lookaheads?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I'm trying to remove a space in front of `<` characters and behind `>` characters in a string. So I used regex101 to figure out how to do this and came up with these 2 regex:

```
/ ?(?=<)/g
/(?<=>) /g
```

I'm aware that Firefox doesn't support negative lookbehinds because of ES2018, but according to regex101 these are both positive lookaheads. Yet when I try these, Firefox returns:

> SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

They are working perfectly fine Chrome though.

Working example (run in Chrome and Firefox):

```js
let str = "this is <some> test";

let patten1 = new RegExp(' ?(?=<)','g');
let patten2 = new RegExp('(?<=>) ','g');

str = str.replace(patten1, '');
str = str.replace(patten2, '');

console.log(str);
```

So my questions are: Is this really a bug? And if so, is there another solution to my problem that will work?

Comment: FF doesn't support lookbehind of any type, positive or negative, yet

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ah that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: They are not both positive lookaheads. `(?=<)` is a positive lookahead and `(?<=>)` is a positive lookbehind.

Comment: Funny how regex101 suddenly shows positive lookbehind instead of lookahead.. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe you might want to write a simple expression that'd be somewhat similar to:

```
\s*(<[^>]*>)\s*
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/I6N4iG/1/)

or

```
\s{0,1}(<[^>]*>)\s{0,1}
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lRekNh/1/)

and replace it with `$1`.

```js
const regex = /\s{0,1}(<[^>]*>)\s{0,1}/g;
const str = `this is <some> test`;
const subst = `$1`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eisDth/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/eisDth/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---